# How to disable the MS Word "macro-free document" warning with code?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an application that dynamically insert VBA code to help building a MS word document with proper bookmarks.  The VBA code doesn't need to be saved with the document itself.

When saving the document, the following warning (unfortunately I can't post an image yet) will pop up that confuses the end users of the application.  Is there a way to disable this within the DocumentBeforeSave event?

**

> The following cannot be saved in a macro-free document: VBA project To
>   save a file with these features, click No to return to the Save As
>   dialog, and then choose a macro-enabled file type in the File Type
>   drop-down. Continue saving as a macro-free document? 
>   buttons: [Yes][No][Help]

**

One idea is to change the document's SaveFormat to an older format in order to prevent this warning from popping up.  But I'm not sure if this change will affect how the document behaves going forward and if it's even possible to modify this property within the DocumentBeforeSave event (the property is a READONLY property).

Thanks in advance for any help on this topic.

The following code will open a word (assuming c:\work\test.docx exist, which can be just a blank word doc).  If you hit the Save button on the word doc, the warning message will show up.  BTW, I'm using Office 2010.

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub testWord()
    Dim wApp As New Word.Application()
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim DataCodeModule As Object = Nothing

    myDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Work\test.docx")

    DataCodeModule = myDoc.VBProject.VBComponents(0).CodeModule
    With DataCodeModule
        .InsertLines(1, "Option Explicit")
        .InsertLines(2, "Sub TestCode()")
        .InsertLines(3, "Selection.InsertAfter ""test""")
        .InsertLines(4, "End Sub")
    End With

    wApp.Visible = True
    myDoc.Activate()
End Sub
```

And once the DocumentBeforeSave is hooked up, I was hoping the following code would disable the warning.  Maybe the DisplayAlerts need to be set as soon as the document is opened?

```
Public Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal doc As Object, ByRef saveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef cancel As Boolean) Handles _officeHelper.DocumentBeforeSave
            Dim WordApp As Object = this.WordApp()
            'WordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
            WordApp.DisplayAlerts = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: CAn you build the Document as a `New` document, rather than using the one your code is in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
'~~> Your Save Code
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
```

**FOLLOWUP**

You are doing it in vb.net. I don't have access to VB.net at the moment but this example below will set you on the right path

Open Word and insert a module and then paste this code

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyClass As New Class1

Sub Sample()
    Set MyClass.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

Now insert a Class Module and paste this code

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, _
SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    ActiveDocument.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll

End Sub
```

Now if you press the save button, you will notice that you won't get that alert any more. :)

Hope you can adapt it as required :)

Comment: That's a great idea, but unfortunately setting the DisplayAlerts to false doesn't stop the warning message from popping up (just tested it)...

Comment: Assuming wdAlertsNone have the value of 0 (I'm doing late binding), this still doesn't prevent the warning message from coming up.  I'm trying to put together a simple code to post here.

Comment: That's strange. I just tried it and it works. Guess I will wait for your sample code.

Comment: ` <TestMethod()>
  Public Sub testWord()
    Dim wApp As New Word.Application()
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim DataCodeModule As Object = Nothing

    myDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Work\test.docx")

    DataCodeModule = myDoc.VBProject.VBComponents(0).CodeModule
    With DataCodeModule
      .InsertLines(1, "Option Explicit")
      .InsertLines(2, "Sub TestCode()")
      .InsertLines(3, "Selection.InsertAfter ""test""")
      .InsertLines(4, "End Sub")
    End With

    wApp.Visible = True
    myDoc.Activate()
  End Sub'

Comment: That's difficult to read. can you edit your question and paste this code there?

Comment: sorry about that.  Still learning how to properly format code here.  I will edit the question and put the sample code there.

Comment: I've tested the VBA code directly in Word and it doesn't appear to work the way that it appears.  If any modification is made on the VBA code, the warning pop up will still show up.

Comment: Can you upload the word document that you created just now and upload it in say wikisend.com and then share the link here

Comment: BTW did you run the code `Sub Sample()` before clicking on the save button?

Comment: Note that I have to save this as a docm file in order to keep the VBA code with the document (which in my application I don't need) [URL=http://wikisend.com/download/136838/test.docm]test.docm[/URL]

Comment: Yes, I need to run Sample(), which I forgot.  This does seem to work.  Just need to figure out why it wasn't behaving the same way within our application.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I simply done this code . It will prompt you to save and also help you in attaching it to email.
It worked for me.
Please try. I gave a command button on top of the sheet.
Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim whatfolder, whatfile As String
whatfolder = InputBox("Type folder name.. Don't type which drive")
whatfile = InputBox("Type file name you want to give")
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\" & whatfolder
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=whatfile & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
ActiveDocument.SendMail
End Sub
```